# Will immutable objects with const parameters be optimized to be instantiated only once by the Kotlin compiler

Tags: java, kotlin, constants, immutability, kotlinc

There are many immutable classes in Java like `String` and primitive wrapper classes, and Kotlin introduced many others like `Range` subclasses and immutable `Collection` subclasses.

For iterating `Range`s, from [Control Flow: if, when, for, while - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops) we already know:

> A `for` loop over a range or an array is compiled to an index-based loop that does not create an iterator object.

However in other scenarios when dealing with `Range`s this optimization is not possible.

When creating such immutable classes with const parameters, or more generally, recursively with const parameters, instantiating the class only once will bring performance gains. (In other words, if we call this a const immutable instantiation, an instantiation is a const immutable instantiation if and only if all its parameters are either constants or const immutable instantiations.) Since the Java compiler doesn't have a mechanism to know whether a class is immutable, does the Kotlin compiler optimize such classes to be instantiated only once, based on its knowledge of its known immutable classes?

For a more specific example of application, consider the following code:

```
repeat(1024) {
    doSomething(('a'..'z').random())
}
```

```
val LOWERCASE_ALPHABETS = 'a'..'z'
repeat(1024) {
    doSomething(LOWERCASE_ALPHABETS.random())
}
```

Would the second one bring any performance improvements?

Comment: Kotlin will optimize many ranges to a normal for loop, avoiding the instantiation of the range object. I don't know if it happens in these cases or not, but I think it will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best thing you can do is to check what instructions the compiler generates.

Let's take the following source code:

```
fun insideRepeat() {
    repeat(1024) {
        doSomething(('a'..'z').random())
    }
}

fun outsideRepeat() {
    val range = 'a'..'z'
    repeat(1024) {
        doSomething(range.random())
    }
}
```

For `insideRepeat` it will generate something like (I added a few comments):

```
    public final static insideRepeat()V
    L0
    LINENUMBER 2 L0
    SIPUSH 1024
    ISTORE 0
    L1
    L2
    ICONST_0
    ISTORE 1
    ILOAD 0
    ISTORE 2
    L3
    ILOAD 1
    ILOAD 2
    IF_ICMPGE L4 // loop termination condition
    L5
    ILOAD 1
    ISTORE 3
    L6
    ICONST_0
    ISTORE 4
    L7 // loop body
    LINENUMBER 3 L7
    BIPUSH 97
    ISTORE 5
    NEW kotlin/ranges/CharRange
    DUP
    ILOAD 5
    BIPUSH 122
    INVOKESPECIAL kotlin/ranges/CharRange.<init> (CC)V // new instance created inside the loop
    INVOKESTATIC FooKt.random (Lkotlin/ranges/CharRange;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    INVOKESTATIC FooKt.doSomething (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    POP
```

While for the `outsideRepeat` it will generate:

```
public final static outsideRepeat()V
L0
LINENUMBER 8 L0
BIPUSH 97
ISTORE 1
NEW kotlin/ranges/CharRange
DUP
ILOAD 1
BIPUSH 122
INVOKESPECIAL kotlin/ranges/CharRange.<init> (CC)V // range created outside loop
ASTORE 0
L1
LINENUMBER 9 L1
SIPUSH 1024
ISTORE 1
L2
L3
ICONST_0
ISTORE 2
ILOAD 1
ISTORE 3
L4
ILOAD 2
ILOAD 3
IF_ICMPGE L5 // termination condition
L6
ILOAD 2
ISTORE 4
L7
ICONST_0
ISTORE 5
L8
LINENUMBER 10 L8
ALOAD 0
INVOKESTATIC FooKt.random (Lkotlin/ranges/CharRange;)Ljava/lang/Object;
INVOKESTATIC FooKt.doSomething (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
POP
```

So it seems like the second version brings performance improvements indeed (also considering the GC will need to deallocate less objects)

Comment: It is entirely possible that this will get optimized at *runtime* to have exactly the same performance.

Comment: that's absolutely true, but I guess it also depends on the specific JVM implementation you're using (or rather the JIT compiler), isn't it?